# C++ macros, expanding n into 1, 2, 3, ... n

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to build a template class for matrices/vectors

I want to expand a macro into something like the following

```
#define ELEMENTS(M, N) expands into

m00, m01, m02, ... , m0N,
m10, m11, m12, ... , m1N,
...
...
...
mm0, mN1, mN2, ... , mMN
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Using an array is easier and more efficient space-wise.

Comment: @AraK If I understand him correctly he wants to expand this into a template argument list. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @AraK its also harder to use =) I want union{ struct{ T ELEMENTS(M, N }; v[N*M]; }

Comment: Probably won't matter to you, but reading from a non-active member of a union is undefined behavior in C++. I.e. reading from v[0] isn't equivalent to reading m00 in that union. On the other hand C99 defines it as the expected implementation defined type punning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is [BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/enum_params.html).

`BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS` itself is only a wrapper around `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`. Looking at the [implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp) shows that it is rather cumbersome and also depends on some tricky headers like `auto_rec.hpp`. Implementing something like that is probably more cumbersome then doing what you have in mind by hand. So, if you don't want to use Boost, I'd rather not do it.

Comment: Er is there a solution outside of using boost? +1

Comment: @aCuria I've tried to explain, why I think this wouldn't be a good idea but gave you some files to look at, should you approach this. Extracting just the one part of Boost.Preprocessor should be feasible as well.